# typesetting a physical law

Tags: environments

How should one type set one of Newton's law?

`\begin{definition}` environment doesn't seem right since it should say the law's name in bold not definition (some number) and `\begin{theorem}` doesn't fit since we are dealing with a law.

Comment: Will `\Begin{description} \item[Newton's first law] Every body .....\end{description}` help?

Comment: @HarishKumar let me see how it looks real quick and let you know.

Comment: @HarishKumar yes that works.  You can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options: the first one (possibly an overkill?), using [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) as a front-end for `amsthm` with a dedicated, unnumbered structure, and the second one using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\normalfont]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=mystyle,
  numbered=no,
  name=Newton's First Law
]{newton}
\usepackage{mdframed}


\begin{document}

\begin{newton}
If there is no net force on an object, then its velocity is constant. The object is either at rest (if its velocity is equal to zero), or it moves with constant speed in a single direction.
\end{newton}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!30,frametitle=Newton's First Law]
If there is no net force on an object, then its velocity is constant. The object is either at rest (if its velocity is equal to zero), or it moves with constant speed in a single direction.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put `*` in the `\newtheorem` command and in the label `{secondlaw*}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem*{secondlaw*}{Newton's Second Law}

\begin{document}

\begin{secondlaw*}  
The variation of the momentum in the time is equal to sum of the forces.
\end{secondlaw*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick hint: If you highlight a code chunk and click on the `{}` "button" in the row above the editing window, the site software will automatically pretty-print the code.