# mdframed being cut across pages

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

Is there a way to prevent this (see image) from happening when you are going onto another page?

[image]

Comment: A very nice bug problem.

Comment: @ClickMe I tried using `\raggedbottom` to see if that would do anything but it didn't.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. That way bug-hunters can attempt solutions without trying to reproduce it from scratch.

Comment: @Werner this occurs on page 32 so I can't just setup an example that puts it in that exact spot.

Comment: @dustin at least, give us your settings for the `mdframed` environment that you are using.

Comment: Do you have `nobreak=true` option for `mdframed` set?

Comment: @PeterGrill no I don't.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I have only the background and title set, respectively.

Comment: @dustin Are you using the settings I suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110600/3954? I've been trying to reproduce your problem without success. Is there any non-text material (a float, for example) near the problematic `mdframed`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using that set up.  Right above it is a `\begin{displaymath} \end{}` equation.

Comment: @dustin perhaps Marco Daniel, the package creator has some clue as what could be going on. He's a regular here, so I'm sure he'll see your question.

Comment: does \begin{samepage} .... \end{samepage} have the desired effect?

Comment: @ADP no nothing changed

Comment: @dustin: Well, does adding `nobreak=true` fix things. That option is intended to prevent exactly the problem you are describing.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes that worked.  Add this as a solution so I can accept it.

Comment: Please show use the definition of your environment and the environment itself. Which version do you use? You can drop me an email too.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel how do I email you?

Comment: In the documentation you can find my email adress.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel sent

Comment: Can you keep up posted in case you find a convenient solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) you need to use `nobreak=true` to prevent page breaks within a frame.